# String Can not be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json

I am making a user login and registration system and have made it.. The registration is working fine and all the data is being saved in MYSQL PHP database. but the problem is that when I try login it doesnot login..

```
  try {
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                if (jsonObject.length() == 0) {
                    returnedUser = null;
                } else {
                    String Name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                    int Age = jsonObject.getInt("age");


                    returnedUser = new User(Name, Age, user.Username, user.Password);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return returnedUser;
        }
```

The Problem Is

```
org.json.JSONException: Value <br><table of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Please Provide me a solution along with explanation.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is about the String which is being responded from Server
check the value it might not be valid json String

Answer (score 0):

Some how your `result` string is not a perfect JSON. Validate your string whether it a perefect JSON by printing it(`System.out.print(result)`). You can validate it [here](http://jsonlint.com/) if you are not sure.

This error comes when there is problem in parsing JSON to string, as also evident by error stack trace.